# Letting go of auto_ptr

Tags: c++, coding-style, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

Occasionally, for fleeting moments, I think auto_ptr is cool.  But most of the time I recognize that there are much simpler techniques that make it irrelevant.  For example, if I want to have an object freed automatically, even if an exception is thrown, I could new up the object and assign to an auto_ptr.  Very cool!  But I could have more easily created my object as a local variable, and let the stack take care of it (duh!).

Thus I was not too surprised when I found [google C++ coding standards](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) banning the use of auto_ptr.  Google states that scoped_ptr should be used instead (if a smart pointer is needed).

I'd like to know if anyone, contrary to my experience, can give a solid reason(s) of when auto_ptr is the *best or simplest* thing to use.  If not, then I suppose I will ban using it myself (following google's lead).

**update**: For those who expressed concern, no I am not adopting google standards.  For example, against google advice, I agree exception-handling should be activated.  I also like using preprocessor macros, such as the [printable enum](http://www.ariasamp.net/brain-dump/cpp-printable-enum/) I made.  It is just the auto_ptr topic that struck me.

**update2**: It turns out my answer comes from two of the responders below, and a [note from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x).  First, Herb Sutter did show a valid use (source-sink idiom and lifetime-linked object composition).  Second, there are shops where TR1 and boost are not available or banned and only C++03 is allowed.  Third, according to Wikipedia, the C++0x spec is deprecating auto_ptr and replacing it with unique_ptr.  So my answer is: use unique_ptr if available to me (on all platforms in consideration) else use auto_ptr for the cases that Sutter depicts.

Comment: Google style guide also bans exceptions. Will we ban exceptions because someone gets them wrong and Google style guide bans them? No.

Comment: don't follow Google guidelines, in general, they are specific for them and include the need of integration with their huge C codebase. (There are many reasons not to use `auto_ptr` though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the simplest thing to use when you need a scoped or unique pointer and you are working in a strict C++03 environment with no access to a tr1 implementation or boost.

Answer (score 7):

Herb Sutter can help you out on this one: http://www.drdobbs.com/184403837

Answer (score 6):

While banning `auto_ptr` seems attractive, but there is one issue:

```
template <typename T>
some_smart_ptr<T> create();
```

What will you replace the `some_smart_ptr` placeholder with ?

The generic answer, `shared_ptr`, is only worth it if the ownership is truly shared, if the function grants the caller exclusive ownership of the resources, it's misleading at best (and a typical case of premature pessimization as far as I am concerned).

On the other hand, in C++03, no other form of smart pointer can deliver: it's impossible, without move semantics, to provide what we'd like here. `auto_ptr` or a naked pointer are the two logical contenders. But then a naked pointer exposes you to the risk of leaks if the caller is careless.

With C++0x, `unique_ptr` advantageously replace `auto_ptr` in every situation.

Answer (score 3):

`std::auto_ptr` still has pointer semantics, so automatic (non-pointer) variables aren't a substitute. In particular, `std::auto_ptr` supports polymorphism and re-assignment. With stack variables you can use references for polymorphism, but references don't allow for re-assignment.

Sometimes `std::auto_ptr` will do just fine. For example, for implementing a pimpl. True, in the vast majority of cases boost' smart pointer library offers better choices for a smart pointer. But right now `std::auto_ptr` is a standard solution, whereas boost's smart pointers aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Using auto_ptr as function return value you will enjoy no copiyng overhead and never have memory leak. `std::auto_ptr<obj> foo()` can be safely called in `{ foo(); }` while `obj *foo()` cannot. boost::shared_ptr can solve this, but with higher overhead.

Also, some objects can't be created on stack because of memory constraints: thread stacks are relatively small. But boost::scoped_ptr is better in this case since it can't be accidentally released.

Answer (score 1):

Well one reason would be that `scoped_ptr` is non-copyable, so it's safer to use and harder to make mistakes with. `auto_ptr` allows transfer of ownership (eg. by passing it another `auto_ptr` as a constructor parameter). If you need to think things like transferring the ownership, the chances are you're better off with a smart pointer like `shared_ptr`.